# javascript adding array to specific index in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to ask how can I add array to the end of another array but the newly added
array is in one index
for example if I want to add

`apples=["green","red","yellow"]`

to

`fruits=["banana","grape"]`

I want the result be like

`fruits=["banana","grape",["green","red","yellow"]]`

and NOT

`["banana","grape","green","red","yellow"]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Help us to help you - for example, by formatting your code and showing what you've tried.

Comment: You add the array the same way you add any other value. Why do you think there's anything special?

Comment: I want to add an array as a single element in the fruits array so fruits[2] will return ["green","red","yellow"]

Comment: I mean the reslut be array with 3 elements the first is banana the second is grape the third is nested aaray apples

Answer (score 1):

If you want to always add the array to the end of the array you can use `.push()` like so:

```js
let apples = ["green","red","yellow"];
let fruits = ["banana","grape"];
fruits.push(apples); // appends the array apples to the end of fruits
console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: I dont want the resultant array be with 5 elements i want it to be with 3 elements and the third element is array apples

Comment: Yes, I understand that, this code snippet does exactly that. Try and access the last index of the fruits array and see for yourself.